# onfocus fires after second click time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, focus

I have an input field, and on it's focus a note should be seen.

```
<input type="text" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" onfocus="craateUserJsObject.showContactEmailNote();"/>
<div id="contact_email_note" class="info_box">Contact email note</div>
```

jQuery code is:

```
showContactEmailNote : function () {
                    var ContactEmail = jQuery('#contact_email');
                    if (typeof ContactEmail.focus(function()
                        {
                           {
                               $("#contact_email_note").show("slow");
                           }
                        }
                    ));
                    if (typeof ContactEmail.focusout(function()
                        {
                           {
                               $("#contact_email_note").hide("slow");
                           }
                        }
                    ));

                 }
```

The problem is that onfocus event only load the note after the second click on the input field. The same is with onclick event.
How can it load on first focus of the field?

Thanks, Dusan

Comment: Why are you using if statements with attaching event handlers?

Comment: `$('#form').on('focus', '#contact_email', handler).on('blur', '#contact_email', handler);` Would be a little easier to digest.

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
$('#contact_email').on('focus blur', function(){
    $("#contact_email_note").toggle("slow");
});
```

And see this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyuz6/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the code is correct, but it still loads after the second focus. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For you code, only add the property css `display: none;` to the `contact_email_note`, you note is visible in the first click, whith the css solve it... see the example...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a more easier code like this one :

**jQuery**

```
$('#contact_email').focusin(function() {
    $("#contact_email_note").show("slow");
}).focusout( function() {
    $("#contact_email_note").hide("slow");
});
```

See working [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/wHdjq/).

**Edit to show the note only once**

```
var noteHasBeenShown = false;
$('#contact_email').focusin(function() {
    if(!noteHasBeenShown) {
        $("#contact_email_note").show("slow");
        noteHasBeenShown = true;
    }
}).focusout( function() {
    $("#contact_email_note").hide("slow");
});
```

**Edit to show the note and don't hide it**

```
$('#contact_email').focusin(function() {
    $("#contact_email_note").show("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the code is correct, but it still loads after the second focus.

Comment: @soyuka in you edit code the note only show in the first time, after the firs time the note not show again...

Comment: That's what he wanted no ? _but it still loads after the second focus._ Or he wants it to show and than stays ?

Comment: I want toshow the note on every focus. All of these answers zou posted are correct in document ready handeler, but i cant figure out why it only works after second focus if i call it in a way i used it with onfocus. I am new with javascript and jquery so forgive me fornot understanding well all of this

Comment: It's your structure which is wrong, post a more specific [fiddle](jsfiddle.net) example, I may be able to help you more.

Comment: I figured it out, i just had to put $(document).ready around function and it shows on the first focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to discover the type of an event, you should use `type` property of the `event` object, you are misusing `typeof` operator, a simple event listener does the trick.

```
$('#contact_email').on('focus blur', function(event){
    $("#contact_email_note").toggle(event.type === 'focus');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the code is correct, but it still loads after the second focus. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Dušan Because you have put the code in the context of `showContactEmailNote` method, remove your `onfocus` attribute and put the code in the document ready handler.

Comment: It works in the document ready handler, but is there a way to show it in a way to create an object on onfocus or onclick event, but to load on first time?